# javascript callback function selection

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, callback, closures

So basically i need to use the each function that i implemented in the filter function so that the filter function return only item in myArray that is greater than 2.  i m totally stuck.

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function each(collection, callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        callback(collection[i]);
    }
}

function filter(collection, test) {
    var returnAr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        if (test(collection[i])) {
            returnAr.push(collection[i])
        }
    }
    //instead of using "for(var i  = 0; i < collection.length; i++)"
    // how can i use the each function i implemented above?

    return returnAr;
}

filter(myArray, function(n) {
    return n > 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `each` function calls its callback by passing each item in the array as a function argument. Therefore the correct way to call it would be:

```
each(collection, function(item) {
    if (test(item)) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Javascript doesn't quite provide a nice self-documenting way of specifying the function signature[1]. Normally this is solved by reading the API documentation. But if this is your own code and it doesn't come with API documentation then you need to look at how the callback is invoked. In this case it is called as:

```
callback(collection[i]);
```

Which tells us that the callback function should accept one argument which is a single item from the array.

[1]: also called prototype, no, not in the javascript sense of the word "prototype", in the C sense of the word "prototype"

Comment: function filter(collection, test)
{
 var returnAr = [];

 each(collection, function(item)
 {
  if(test(item))
  {
   returnAr.push(item)
  }
 })

 return returnAr;
}

Comment: THANKS slebetman, ur comment fix the last serious syntax error. also big THANK to cdosborn. damn my pair programming guy, he could have said encapsulation or f(g(h(x))) and i would be in the right direction. i cannot really blame him though because his boss force him to do the procedure like he did.

Comment: It is a good learning experience. It sometimes just takes one trivial example to give you that AHA moment.

Comment: i totally didnt realize that every time i use a "callback" i need to IMPLEMENT it lol. i was prepping my ammunition in this interview so i have down binary search, mergesort, link link(ok only lol), tree(ok only) but just barely concentrate on callback. damn, in return i know how to remove transmission and/or engine quickly with very little tool and not expensive tool at all. malaysia have very nice japanese cars compare to america. enjoy those JDM cars lol

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The 'each' function above executes a callback on all items of a collection. But in 'filter' you are deciding whether you want an item in the resultant array based on result of the callback. So 'filter' and 'each' are both different operations. Whatever you are doing in the current function is right way of filtering.

Answer (score 0):

The signature for `each` takes an array like thing, and a function that gets called with the element.

```
function each(collection, callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        callback(collection[i]);
    }
}
```

It seems like your callback should just do what this does:

```
    if (test(collection[i])) {
        returnAr.push(collection[i])
    }
```

Note that collection[i] is the first argument to the callback.

Your callback will have the form:

```
function(element) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: your code is exactly like mine lol. it doesnt work compare to the correct answer which is the original post code up there.

Comment: i'm not going to give you the answer, i'm trying to push you towards it

Comment: lol. nice. i m reading Eloquent Javascript higher order funtion and hope i can reach whatever u have in mind lol.

Comment: That book is excellent! Each replaces the for loop and nothing else, so you have to encapsulate your test inside the callback. Filter uses the callback just to get true or false, but each will use the callback to change `returnAr`

Comment: i m almost there my friend lol. son of a beach, my partner who was doing pair programming went in circle forever. man. what ur saying sound like f(g(h(x))) lol right? that what on my mind for dinner

Comment: each takes an array and a function. What do you want to do to each element? You want to test them and determine whether or not they will be part of the result that is returned. That functionality you have to write into the callback.

Answer (score 0):

If you really only want to filter the array on the condition you give, this is all the code you need:

```
myArray.filter(function(item) { return item > 2 })
```

Comment: this answer is inappropriate given the context

Comment: Michael, u have to leave everything alone and modify the implementation of the filter function only because that where the problem is. yeah it very strict so u have to play along with themlol

Comment: Well, your question is not clear why you want to implement something the EcmaScript language has implemented already for you.

Comment: yes i know ecmascript have such feature. the point is to practice encapsulation. lol sorry...they force me to understand and use this idea of encapsulation